# The relation between functional factorization and sorting

Tags: probability, optimization

I've recently read the following paragraph in a mathematical magazine:

> To illustrate the benefits of functional factorization, consider a
>   large field of $N>>1$ stones. Each stone is suited for making exactly
>   one of k possible tools: hammer, arrowhead, ... . One fine day(!), the
>   tool maker organizes his tribe to sort all the stones in the field
>   into $k$ piles, one for each tool. Under suitable probabilistic
>   assumptions, and taking into account search and sort times, *the sorted architecture is roughly $k$-times more efficient than no
>   architecture*, given the tool maker will make $N(\rightarrow \infty)$
>   tools over his lifetime.

I can't see how it has concluded that: *the sorted architecture is roughly $k$-times more efficient than no architecture*.

Is there anyone to explain the case a little bit formally?!

Comment: It would help if you cited where you saw this quote.

Comment: In a comment on a deleted answer, you berate the answerer for not paying attention to the definition of "functional factorization". Care to tell us what that definition is?

Comment: @JacobManaker Perhaps not the original source, but see http://www.cas.mcmaster.ca/~leduc/slidesCAS704/cas745/Wonham_SCDES_20130701.pdf exercise 1.4.3